# Обращение к работающему процессу

Tags: linux, процесс, демон, unix-socket

Появилась необходимость обратится к работающему процессу т.е. передать какие-то данные в запущенный процесс и далее получить из него какую-то наработанную инфу. Без создания нового процесса.

Пример: линукс-демон коннектится по ssh к серваку и держит соединение открытым. К демону обращаются скрипты, передают ему мак-адрес, а демон передает мак серваку, принимает ответ севера и передает обратно в скрипт.

Это нужно для того что-бы не уложить сервак 2000тыс. Обращений в секунду

Хочу знать как реализовать именно процесс обращения к демону? Где почитать почитать? В какую сторону копать? Через сокеты, сигналы, события?

`$linux_demon.py` параметр - такой вариант не подходит т.к. создается процесс.

пропала возможность комментировать

буду курить в сторону UDP в AF_UNIX домене
Огромное спасибо ответившим.
По результатам отпишусь.

Разобрался!!!!
Сокет в файловом пространстве имен или так называемый UNIX сокет - вот ключ к решению
Полезная иформация
[Citforum](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/sockets/)
[Wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)
[Журнал VR-online](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/imenovannye-kanaly-i-sokety-unix-prosto-o-slozhnom-1902)

Comment: подходит-подходит, новый процесс должен отыскать бегущий процесс, переслать ему параметр и самозавершиться.

Comment: А если использовать gdb?

Comment: to:VladD

т.е. если я напишу в баш "linux_demon.py параметр" то параметр будет передан в уже работающий процесс?

Comment: to alexlz:

мысль интересная, посмотрю в сторону отладчиков.

Comment: @Rom4eg, не думаю, что работа с демоном через отладчик будет эффективной.

Про скрипты (язык какой? размер и тип данных ответа) поподробнее если можно.

Comment: @Rom4eg: нет, будет запущен новый процесс, который уж сам должен будет позаботиться о связи со старым.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что самым лучшим будет обращение процессов к даймону через сокет

Comment: @mikillskegg, вопрос тут в том, могут ли **скрипты** создавать сокеты. 

Если могут, я бы на UDP в AF_UNIX домене попробовал. Еще вариант shared memory, но опять же вопрос упирается в возможности *скрипта*.

Comment: @avp: [документация](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html) утверждает, что сокеты доступны. В крайнем случае можно сигнал отправить :-)

Comment: @avp, Язык Python и демон и скрипт на нем-же. ответ "строки" возможно несколько сотен, ответ так-же перерабатывается демоном.

суть: демон по ssh удаленно выполняет команду и забирает выхлоп от этой команды. необходимо передать демону параметр для выполнения команд на серваке.

схема такая
1 скрипт коннектится к управляемому свичу берет мак с порта и передает его демону 
2 демон коннектится к серваку и выполняет 
"команда полученный_от_скрипта_мак" 
3 забирает выхлоп от п.2
4 отдает скрипту выхлоп, скрипт на основании выхлопа, рисует html страничку

Comment: наверное сокеты, будет лучшим решением. всем спасибо.

Comment: @Rom4eg, в общем, демон это RPC proxy. 

Если скриптов **очень много** (но это вряд ли) попробуйте UDP на локальном хосте через юникс-домен.

Соединение по TCP скрипта с демоном программируется наверное проще, но надо не забывать, что обычно число файловых дескрипторов процесса в линуксе ограничено 1024.

Answer (score 1):

ответ скопирован из вопроса.

---

Сокет в файловом пространстве имен или так называемый UNIX сокет - вот ключ к решению
Полезная иформация:

- [Citforum](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/sockets/)
- [Wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)
- [Журнал VR-online](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/imenovannye-kanaly-i-sokety-unix-prosto-o-slozhnom-1902)